# Hbase indexer for Solr

Tags: solr, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I’m trying to index data from a Hbase table using lucid works hbase indexer , I would like to know if Solr , Hbase indexer & Hbase have to use the same zookeeper?

Can my Solr instance be independent while hbase and Hbase indexer are together reporting to zookeeper1 while Solr reports to its own zookeeper ?

Im following the below url 
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/1181/hbase-indexing-to-solr-with-hdp-search-in-hdp-23.html

Answer (score -1):

It is up to our decisions whether go with the same zookeeper or the different independent one.

Because for hbase-zookeeper production setup zookeeper recommend the 3 node setup  which means 3 zookeeper required for that setup. So we can make use of the same server for solr also.

It will help us to reduce the number of servers.

Zookeeper is light weight server which will be used to monitor solr server, so it would be good to keep the zookeeper outside the solr server for production run.

Comment: The question is - should the same zookeeper instance say I have 3 zookeepers zk1,zk2,zk3 which are used by my hbase and Hbase indexer . Can solr be configured to use its own zookeeper zk4,zk5,zk6 ? And will the Hbase indexer be able to index hbase data to solr ?

Comment: Yes we can make use of the same zookeeper,